# Search for a specific word in text file - program counts word fragments as matches

Tags: java

```
 If I wanna search for a word like "and" for example and my text file is 


Saturday and Sunday 
Hand
```

My program will count the word hand as a match because it contains the word and. I do not know how to fix it especially because the search term is declared as user input..

Comment: Javascript question tag removed -- this question has nothing to do with javascript.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming, your search letter will never be first word of each sentence. Most simplest solution is add an extra whitespace  before your word.

Something like `searchW=" "+searchW`

Comment: Also a space after, but that assumes the word is not the last one (e.g. hand - handy)

Answer (score 0):

There is another problem with your code - if you have multiple matches in one line, it will only count it once. The reason for both of those is the way you search the file - you check if each line contains the string. If you want the exact matches of words, the simple way to do it is tokenizing the line like so:

```
String[] tokens = text.split("\\s+");
```

Now you have an array of strings, each of those is one word in the line that is currently being processed. Next you can do a simple comparison using `equalsIgnoreCase()` (bonus - works even when the word is capitalized).

You can of course modify the delimeters passed to the split function to include punctuation and more if that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
   File file=null;
   boolean inputFile=false;
    do
    {
      System.out.print("Enter a filename:");
      String fileName = scan.nextLine();
       inputFile= new File(fileName).isFile();
       if(inputFile){
           file=new File(fileName);
           inputFile=true;
       }

    }while(!inputFile);

    Scanner scanned = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter a word to search for: ");
    String searchW = scanned.next();
    int count = 0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
    String text=null;
    while(in.hasNextLine())
    { 
        text=in.nextLine();
      if(text.contains(searchW))
      { 
        count++;
        System.out.println(text); 
      }
    }
    System.out.println("The word" + " " + searchW + " " +  "was found" + " " + count + " " + "time(s) in this file");
    scan.close();
    in.close();
    scanned.close();
   }
  }
```

Suggestions:
1. Do not use file.exists() to check file. it mainely to check directories. it will give exception if file path is invalid.
2. use do while to get valid path from user.

Comment: Why to removed your program. this is modification to your previous program.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please enter the filename: ");
                String filename = scan.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter a word: ");
                String wordname = scan.nextLine();

                int count = 0;
                try (LineNumberReader r = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                        for (String element : line.split(" ")) {
                            if (element.equalsIgnoreCase(wordname)) {
                                count++;
                                System.out.println("Word found at line " + r.getLineNumber());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("The word " + wordname + " appears " + count + " times.");
            }
```